# Skipping precaching: Cannot read property 'concat' of null`

Tags: json, polymer, laravel-5.1, service-worker, polymer-starter-kit

Here's my question: How might I try to get rid of the 'skipping precaching' and cache everything that comes in from https://laoadventist.info/beta/r as the precache list?

Also, is it correct for me to set `precache="https://laoadventist.info/beta/r"` or should I be setting that to a function that grabs the data and returns it instead?

`Skipping precaching: Cannot read property 'concat' of null`
comes out on the console when using [My Polymer App](https://laoadventist.info/app/#!/app/)

```
<platinum-sw-cache default-cache-strategy="fastest" cache-config-file="cache-config.json" precache="https://laoadventist.info/beta/r">
```

I am assuming correctly I can precahce a URL like this, right?

I am trying to load a json result from laravel 5.1 to set what my precache should be... I know it's not the most elegant, but I'm new to Polymer, cache, service workers, etc, and using this app as a learning opportunity. It'll be a bit different at the end of the day, but for now I just want to load everything. :)

I want to precache all of the data so that a user can fully utilize this app when offline (though later I'll set it up so that they don't have to precache loads and loads of json requests, only the ones they want, like per book - but that's for later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a array of resource URLs that you want precached, the cleanest way to specify them is to use the `cacheConfigFile` option and to point to a JSON file that contains your array as its `precache` property. Take a look at the example in the docs for `cacheConfigFile`: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/platinum-sw?active=platinum-sw-cache

You shouldn't have to use the `precache` attribute on the element if you're using `cacheConfigFile`.

It sounds like you're using Polymer Starter Kit, and that will create the JSON config file and populate it for you with an array corresponding to your local resources. But if you'd like to specify additional resources to be precached, you can modify the build process to append those URLs to the auto-generated list.

The reason you're seeing that error is because you're pointing to a [JSON config file](https://laoadventist.info/app/cache-config.json) that is effectively empty, and is just meant for the development environment.

Comment: Your suggestion got me past that specific hurdle :). I did several things, and tried to implement solution fully - finally just added a precache array in cache-config.json manually, and not the gulp built dist version. Any limits on how many URLs in precache array? Note the 414 Request-URI Too Long issue #53 [link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-sw/issues/53) - Seen this code a couple times, but not consistently. Reading and researching docs / source, but still scratching head as to mechanics.

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-sw/issues/53 should not be an issue when you use the external JSON config file. Setting `precacheFingerprint` within the file is recommended to trigger downloading additional files that are added to the `precache` array, and that takes the place of having to serialize the array and include it in the service worker's URL.

Comment: Ok, so the ultimate limit to sw cache seems to be the time period it takes to obtain everything. If I do more than a couple hundred, I get a service worker timeout. Asked a separate question about getting around that limit using dom-repeat. [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453732/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-dom-repeat-on-a-platinum-service-worker)